# How to close Excel file which is opened manually

Tags: java, excel

I opened .xlsx file and then trying to run selenium java code, after all test cases passed error comes like excel file is used in other process, and then test cases are fail.

```
try {
        // Provide the path to the Excel file you want to close
        String filePath = "C:/Users/ManojTambe/Desktop/ReadWriteData.xlsx";

        // Create a ProcessBuilder for the taskkill command
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("taskkill", "/F", "/FI", "WINDOWTITLE eq " + filePath + " - Excel");
        
        // Start the process
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        
        // Wait for the process to complete
        process.waitFor();
        
        System.out.println("Closed Excel file successfully: " + filePath);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: In which operating system? 
Also do you run on privliged?
I know that on widnows if you do not run as admin, it tends to prevent you from closing files an admin prilige open.

Comment: Use finally block to close